# Ruby - Compare two Enumerators elegantly

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I've got two long streams of numbers coming from two different sources (binary data) in Ruby (1.9.2).

The two sources are encapsulated in the form of two [Enumerators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerator.html).

I want to check that the two streams are exactly equal.

I've come with a couple solutions, but both seem quite inelegant.

The first one simply transforms both into an array:

```
def equal_streams?(s1, s2)
  s1.to_a == s2.to_a
end
```

This works, but it is not very performant, memory-wise, specially if the streams have lots of information.

The other option is... ugh.

```
def equal_streams?(s1, s2)
  s1.each do |e1|
    begin
      e2 = s2.next
      return false unless e1 == e2 # Different element found
    rescue StopIteration
      return false # s2 has run out of items before s1
    end
  end

  begin
    s2.next
  rescue StopIteration
    # s1 and s2 have run out of elements at the same time; they are equal
    return true
  end

  return false

end
```

So, is there a simpler, more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Enumerable#zip would be more elegant, but will most likely not have any improvement in terms of performance.

Comment: It looks like the high-performance way to handle this in Ruby 1.9 would be to use fibers/coroutines.  See http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers.

Comment: @Steve: The problem with `zip` is that it creates arrays internally, no matter what Enumerable you pass. There's another problem with length of input params.

Comment: @Mladen: I know -- that's why I said it would most likely not have any improvement in performance.

Comment: @Mladen: I had a look at the C code, and I'm not sure. I've asked about it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487747/does-rubys-enumerablezip-create-arrays-internally

Comment: @Andrew: Perhaps I phrased it bad, `zip` actually always _returns_ an array of arrays (can be seen in the docs), which means that it will internally "uncoil" any passed Enumerable, even a lazy one (such as generator), into an array. I hadn't actually dived into YARV source. I have implemented something similar which works lazily and returns an Enumerator [here](http://jablan.radioni.ca/post/3625157848/c), but it's not perfect fit for this question either.

Comment: @Mladen: `1.times.zip(1.times) {|x,y| puts x, y; 42}` prints out 0, 0 and returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, saw the other thread, I see I was wrong about `zip`. Not sure how it can be used though, as it looks to me that block-form of `zip` can be used only in `each`-like context, not passed around as a new Enumerable (so it could be for example `all?`-ed)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a slight refactoring to your code, assuming that your streams do not include an element `:eof`.

```
def equal_streams?(s1, s2)
  loop do
    e1 = s1.next rescue :eof
    e2 = s2.next rescue :eof
    return false unless e1 == e2
    return true if e1 == :eof
  end
end
```

Using a keyword like `loop` should be faster than using a method like `each`.

Comment: I like this one very much. It didn't occur to me that I could use a "guard" value, such as the :eof symbol in your example. Thanks!

Comment: Oh -- I had it in my head that we needed a solution enumerables that repeatedly invoke the block passed to #each.  So long as we can pull, this is a great solution though.  If it had to work with enumerables, then coroutines would be needed.

Answer (score 7):

Comparing them one element at a time is probably the best you're going to be able to do but you can do it nicer than your "ugh" solution:

```
def grab_next(h, k, s)
  h[k] = s.next
rescue StopIteration
end

def equal_streams?(s1, s2)
  loop do
    vals = { }
    grab_next(vals, :s1, s1)
    grab_next(vals, :s2, s2)
    return true  if(vals.keys.length == 0)  # Both of them ran out.
    return false if(vals.keys.length == 1)  # One of them ran out early.
    return false if(vals[:s1] != vals[:s2]) # Found a mismatch.
  end
end
```

The tricky part is differentiating between just one stream running out and both running out. Pushing the `StopIteration` exception into a separate function and using the absence of a key in a hash is a fairly convenient way of doing that. Just checking `vals[:s1]` will cause problems if your stream contains `false` or `nil` but checking for the presence of a key solves that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I liked sawa's a bit more, but +1 for your time!

Comment: @kikito: That's cool, I upvoted sawa's answer too. Sawa and I are using pretty much the same logic, I'm just using the absence of a hash key to signal the end rather than a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). If you know that you're never going to have the `:eof` symbol in your streams then there's no need for the extra machinery to avoid using a sentinel.

Comment: You're right. Mine had a slight possibility of conflict with `:eof`. +1 for a more general solution than mine.

Comment: @sawa: But `:eof` is probably the best choice for a sentinel and the specific case involves "streams of numbers", if the `:eof` symbol appears in a stream of numbers then kikito has more problems on his hands than a reserved sentinel value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shot of doing it by creating an alternative for `Enumerable#zip`, which works lazily and doesn't create an entire array. It's combining [my implementation](http://jablan.radioni.ca/post/3625157848/c) of Closure's `interleave` and other two answers here (using sentinel value to indicate end of the `Enumerable` has been reached - the fact causing the problem is that `next` rewinds the `Enumerable` once it reached the end).

This solution supports multiple parameters, so you can compare *n* structures at once.

```
module Enumerable
  # this should be just a unique sentinel value (any ideas for more elegant solution?)
  END_REACHED = Object.new

  def lazy_zip *others
    sources = ([self] + others).map(&:to_enum)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      loop do
        sources, values = sources.map{|s|
          [s, s.next] rescue [nil, END_REACHED]
        }.transpose
        raise StopIteration if values.all?{|v| v == END_REACHED}
        yielder.yield values.map{|v| v == END_REACHED ? nil : v}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, when you have variant of `zip` which works lazily and doesn't stop iteration when the first enumerable reaches the end, you can use `all?` or `any?` to actually check corresponding elements for equality.

```
# zip would fail here, as it would return just [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]:
p [1,2,3].lazy_zip([1,2,3,4]).all?{|l,r| l == r}
#=> false

# this is ok
p [1,2,3,4].lazy_zip([1,2,3,4]).all?{|l,r| l == r}
#=> true

# comparing more than two input streams:
p [1,2,3,4].lazy_zip([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]).all?{|vals|
  # check for equality by checking length of the uniqued array
  vals.uniq.length == 1
}
#=> false
```

Comment: "which works lazily and doesn't create an entire array" - zip doesn't usually create an entire array either: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486107/ruby-compare-two-enumerators-elegantly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487747/does-rubys-enumerablezip-create-arrays-internally

Comment: My comment was linking to this question. Sorry, total fail on my part!

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in the comments, here is zip-based solution, first wrapping block version of `zip` within an `Enumerator`, then using it to compare corresponding elements.

It works, but there is already mentioned edge case: if the first stream is shorter than the other, remaining elements from the other will be discarded (see the example below).

I have marked this answer as community wiki as other members could improve on it.

```
def zip_lazy *enums
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    head, *tail = enums
    head.zip(*tail) do |values|
      yielder.yield values
    end
  end
end

p zip_lazy(1..3, 1..4).all?{|l,r| l == r}
#=> true
p zip_lazy(1..3, 1..3).all?{|l,r| l == r}
#=> true
p zip_lazy(1..4, 1..3).all?{|l,r| l == r}
#=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2-source example using a fiber/co-routine.  It's a bit long-winded, but it's very explicit about its behavior, which is nice.

```
def zip_verbose(enum1, enum2)
  e2_fiber = Fiber.new do
    enum2.each{|e2| Fiber.yield true, e2 }
    Fiber.yield false, nil
  end
  e2_has_value, e2_val = true, nil
  enum1.each do |e1_val|
    e2_has_value, e2_val = e2_fiber.resume if e2_has_value
    yield [true, e1_val], [e2_has_value, e2_val]
  end
  return unless e2_has_value
  loop do
    e2_has_value, e2_val = e2_fiber.resume
    break unless e2_has_value
    yield [false, nil], [e2_has_value, e2_val]
  end
end

def zip(enum1, enum2)
  zip_verbose(enum1, enum2) {|e1, e2| yield e1[1], e2[1] }
end

def self.equal?(enum1, enum2)
  zip_verbose(enum1, enum2) do |e1,e2|
    return false unless e1 == e2
  end
  return true
end
```