# Does Ruby's Enumerable#zip create arrays internally?

Tags: c, ruby, array-merge, yarv

In [Ruby - Compare two Enumerators elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486107/ruby-compare-two-enumerators-elegantly), it was said

> The problem with zip is that it
>   creates arrays internally, no matter
>   what Enumerable you pass. There's
>   another problem with length of input
>   params

I had a look at the implementation of Enumerable#zip in YARV, and saw

```
static VALUE
enum_zip(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)
{
    int i;
    ID conv;
    NODE *memo;
    VALUE result = Qnil;
    VALUE args = rb_ary_new4(argc, argv);
    int allary = TRUE;

    argv = RARRAY_PTR(args);
    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        VALUE ary = rb_check_array_type(argv[i]);
        if (NIL_P(ary)) {
            allary = FALSE;
            break;
        }
        argv[i] = ary;
    }
    if (!allary) {
        CONST_ID(conv, "to_enum");
        for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
            argv[i] = rb_funcall(argv[i], conv, 1, ID2SYM(id_each));
        }
    }
    if (!rb_block_given_p()) {
        result = rb_ary_new();
    }
    /* use NODE_DOT2 as memo(v, v, -) */
    memo = rb_node_newnode(NODE_DOT2, result, args, 0);
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, allary ? zip_ary : zip_i, (VALUE)memo);

    return result;
}
```

Am I understanding the following bits correctly?

Check whether all of the arguments are arrays, and if so, replace some indirect reference to the array with a direct reference

```
    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        VALUE ary = rb_check_array_type(argv[i]);
        if (NIL_P(ary)) {
            allary = FALSE;
            break;
        }
        argv[i] = ary;
    }
```

If they aren't all arrays, create an enumerator instead

```
    if (!allary) {
        CONST_ID(conv, "to_enum");
        for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
            argv[i] = rb_funcall(argv[i], conv, 1, ID2SYM(id_each));
        }
    }
```

Create an array of arrays only if a block isn't given

```
    if (!rb_block_given_p()) {
        result = rb_ary_new();
    }
```

If everything is an array, use `zip_ary`, otherwise use `zip_i`, and call a block on each set of values

```
    /* use NODE_DOT2 as memo(v, v, -) */
    memo = rb_node_newnode(NODE_DOT2, result, args, 0);
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, allary ? zip_ary : zip_i, (VALUE)memo);
```

Return an array of arrays if no block is given, else return nil (`Qnil`)?

```
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll be using 1.9.2-p0 as that's what I have on hand.

The `rb_check_array_type` function looks like this:

```
VALUE
rb_check_array_type(VALUE ary)
{
    return rb_check_convert_type(ary, T_ARRAY, "Array", "to_ary");  
}
```

And `rb_check_convert_type` looks like this:

```
VALUE
rb_check_convert_type(VALUE val, int type, const char *tname, const char *method)
{
    VALUE v;

    /* always convert T_DATA */
    if (TYPE(val) == type && type != T_DATA) return val;
    v = convert_type(val, tname, method, FALSE);
    if (NIL_P(v)) return Qnil;
    if (TYPE(v) != type) {
        const char *cname = rb_obj_classname(val);
        rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "can't convert %s to %s (%s#%s gives %s)",
                 cname, tname, cname, method, rb_obj_classname(v));
    }
    return v;
}
```

Note the `convert_type` call. This looks a lot like C version of [`Array.try_convert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000208) and `try_convert` just happens to look like this:

```
/*   
 *  call-seq:
 *     Array.try_convert(obj) -> array or nil
 *
 *  Try to convert <i>obj</i> into an array, using +to_ary+ method. 
 *  Returns converted array or +nil+ if <i>obj</i> cannot be converted
 *  for any reason. This method can be used to check if an argument is an
 *  array.
 *   
 *     Array.try_convert([1])   #=> [1]
 *     Array.try_convert("1")   #=> nil
 *
 *     if tmp = Array.try_convert(arg)
 *       # the argument is an array
 *     elsif tmp = String.try_convert(arg)
 *       # the argument is a string
 *     end
 *
 */
static VALUE
rb_ary_s_try_convert(VALUE dummy, VALUE ary)
{
    return rb_check_array_type(ary);
}
```

So, yes, the first loop is looking for anything in `argv` that is not an array and setting the `allary` flag if it finds such a thing.

In `enum.c`, we see this:

```
id_each = rb_intern("each");
```

So `id_each` is an internal reference for the Ruby `each` iterator method. And in `vm_eval.c`, we have this:

```
/*!  
 * Calls a method 
 * \param recv   receiver of the method
 * \param mid    an ID that represents the name of the method
 * \param n      the number of arguments
 * \param ...    arbitrary number of method arguments  
 *
 * \pre each of arguments after \a n must be a VALUE.
 */
VALUE
rb_funcall(VALUE recv, ID mid, int n, ...)
```

So this:

```
argv[i] = rb_funcall(argv[i], conv, 1, ID2SYM(id_each));
```

Is calling `to_enum` (with, essentially, the [default argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001036)) on whatever is in `argv[i]`.

So, the end result of the first `for` and `if` blocks is that `argv` is either full of arrays or full of enumerators rather than possibly being a mix of the two. But note how the logic works: if something is found that isn't an array, then everything becomes an enumerator. The first part of the `enum_zip` function will wrap arrays in enumerators (which is essentially free or at least cheap enough not to worry about) but won't expand enumerators into arrays (which could be quite expensive). Earlier versions might have gone the other way (prefer arrays over enumerators), I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader or historians.

The next part:

```
if (!rb_block_given_p()) {
    result = rb_ary_new();
}
```

Creates a new empty array and leaves it in `result` if `zip` is being called without a block. And here we should note what [`zip` returns](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001517):

```
enum.zip(arg, ...) → an_array_of_array
enum.zip(arg, ...) {|arr| block } → nil
```

If there is a block, then there is nothing to return and `result` can stay as `Qnil`; if there isn't a block, then we need an array in `result` so that an array can be returned.

From `parse.c`, we see that `NODE_DOT2` is a double-dot range but it looks like they're just using the new node as a simple three element struct; `rb_new_node` just allocates an object, sets some bits, and assigns three values in a struct:

```
NODE*
rb_node_newnode(enum node_type type, VALUE a0, VALUE a1, VALUE a2)
{
    NODE *n = (NODE*)rb_newobj();

    n->flags |= T_NODE;
    nd_set_type(n, type);

    n->u1.value = a0;
    n->u2.value = a1;
    n->u3.value = a2;

    return n;
}
```

`nd_set_type` is just a bit fiddling macro. Now we have `memo` as just a three element struct. This use of `NODE_DOT2` appears to be a convenient kludge.

The `rb_block_call` function appears to be the core internal iterator. And we see our friend `id_each` again so we'll be doing an `each` iteration. Then we see a choice between `zip_i` and `zip_ary`; this is where the inner arrays are created and pushed onto `result`. The only difference between `zip_i` and `zip_ary` appears to be the StopIteration exception handling in `zip_i`.

At this point we've done the zipping and we either have the array of arrays in `result` (if there was no block) or we have `Qnil` in `result` (if there was a block).

---

**Executive Summary**: The first loop explicitly avoids expanding enumerators into arrays. The `zip_i` and `zip_ary` calls will only work with non-temporary arrays if they have to build an array of arrays as a return value. So, if you call `zip` with at least one non-array enumerator and use the block form, then it is enumerators all the way down and the  "problem with zip is that it creates arrays internally" does not happen. Reviewing 1.8 or other Ruby implementations is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: "If there is no block, then there is nothing to return and result can stay as Qnil" - do you mean "If there is a block"?

Comment: @Andrew: Right, corrected. I was writing this at 05:00 after all :)

Comment: What does "memo" mean? Is it short for memoization?

Comment: @Andrew: They might be using "memo" in the ["memoization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) sense but I think the "piece of paper" sense better represents the use; keep in mind that Matz is Japanese so his colloquial English won't match ours. I probably would have called it "state" or "contex". If you look inside `rb_block_call`, you'll see that parameter referred to as the rather generic `data2`, it is just a little bag of data that is carried around during the iteration.

Comment: @mu is too short: or it may mean "memory", I guess.

Comment: @Andrew: Possibly, the same "memo" terminology appears in the [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) documentation.