# Is there Ruby documentation that can verify that Enumerable.to_a calls each internally?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I can write a short example that verifies that `to_a` of `Enumerable` calls `each` internally. Here it is:

```
class MyFooClass
  include Enumerable
  def initialize
    @members = [1, 2, 3]
  end
  def each
    puts "each is now called"
    @members.each{ |m| yield(m) }
  end
end

a = MyFooClass.new
puts "let us convert to array"
g = a.to_a
```

The output is:

```
let us convert to array
each is now called
```

Note that `each` is not member of `Enumerable`, but `to_a` is. Also, if I remove the definition of `each` from my class, then code crashes with the following message:

```
in `to_a': undefined method `each' for #<MyFooClass:0x997c1ac @members=[1, 2, 3]> (NoMethodError)
```

I am wondering whether there is Ruby official documentation about this, that would document the fact that `to_a` (which is member of `Enumerable`) goes through `each` method in your class. Please, do not direct me to source code of `to_a`. I do not consider this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable):

> The `Enumerable` mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. **The class must provide a method `each`**, which yields successive members of the collection.

Emphasis mine. So all of the iterative behavior of Enumerable is based on the class's `each` method; the ordering parts of the Enumerable interface (`min`, `max`, `sort`) use `<=>` but that's not important here.

The supplied `each` method is the only defined way that Enumerable has to interact with the class that mixes it in. Enumerable supplies a `to_a` method so it must use `each` to implement it.

As an aside, Enumerable does its best not to call `to_a` unless it has to, it tries to keep everything as an Enumerable to avoid having to exhaust the enumeration to build an Array that could be expensive in both time and space. The answer that [Yossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342859/yossi) pointed out is more about *when* Enumerable calls `to_a` rather than *how* (but that answer is interesting reading nonetheless ;).

Answer (score 1):

Note the `id_each` in the code of [`#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.src/M001478.html):

```
static VALUE
enum_to_a(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE ary = rb_ary_new();

    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, argc, argv, collect_all, ary);
    OBJ_INFECT(ary, obj);

    return ary;
}
```

For deeper explanation see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487747/does-rubys-enumerablezip-create-arrays-internally) question.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the ascetic explanation in the manual which mu pointed to, there is [following passage](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) in Pickaxe book as well, which is defacto king of Ruby introductory books:

> Well, your classes can support all these neat-o features, thanks to
>   the magic of mixins and module Enumerable. All you have to do is write
>   an iterator called each, which returns the elements of your collection
>   in turn. Mix in Enumerable, and suddenly your class supports things
>   such as map, include?, and find_all?.