# Best way to interleave two enums in ruby?

Tags: ruby, enums

I'm looking for a more elegant way of blending together two SQL resultsets with a given ratio. Within each of them I want them to be worked through in the same order they come in, but I want to interleave the processing to achieve a desired blend.

I realised this can be made into a very generic method working with two enums and yielding items to process, so I've written this method which I'm simultaneously quite proud of (nice generic solution) and quite ashamed of.

```rb
def combine_enums_with_ratio(enum_a, enum_b, desired_ratio)
  a_count = 1
  b_count = 1
  a_finished = false
  b_finished = false
  loop do
    ratio_so_far = a_count / b_count.to_f
    if !a_finished && (b_finished || ratio_so_far <= desired_ratio)
      begin
        yield enum_a.next
        a_count += 1
      rescue StopIteration
        a_finished = true
      end
    end

    if !b_finished && (a_finished || ratio_so_far > desired_ratio)
      begin
        yield enum_b.next
        b_count += 1
      rescue StopIteration
        b_finished = true
      end
    end

    break if a_finished && b_finished
  end
end
```

Ashamed because it's clearly written in a very imperative style. Not looking very rubyish. Maybe there's a way of using one of ruby's nice declarative looping methods, except they don't seem to work holding open two enums like this. So then I believe I'm left having to rescue an exception as part of control flow like this, which feels very dirty. I'm missing java's `hasNext()` method.

Is there a better way?

I did find a similar question about *comparing* enums: [Ruby - Compare two Enumerators elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486107/ruby-compare-two-enumerators-elegantly) . Some compact answers, but not particularly solving it, and my problem involving unequal lengths and unequal yielding seems trickier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a shorter and more general approach:

```
def combine_enums_with_ratio(ratios)
  return enum_for(__method__, ratios) unless block_given?

  counts = ratios.transform_values { |value| Rational(1, value) }

  until counts.empty?
    begin
      enum, _ = counts.min_by(&:last)
      yield enum.next
      counts[enum] += Rational(1, ratios[enum])
    rescue StopIteration
      counts.delete(enum)
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of two enums, it takes a hash of `enum => ratio` pairs.

At first, it creates a `counts` hash using the ratio's reciprocal, i.e. `enum_a => 3, enum_b => 2` becomes:

```
counts = { enum_a => 1/3r, enum_b => 1/2r }
```

Then, within a loop, it fetches the hash's minimum value, which is `enum_a` in the above example. It yields its `next` value and increment its `counts` ratio value:

```
counts[enum_a] += 1/3r

counts #=> {:enum_a=>(2/3), :enum_b=>(1/2)}
```

On the next iteration, `enum_b` has the smallest value, so its `next` value will be yielded and its ratio be incremented:

```
counts[enum_b] += 1/2r

counts #=> {:enum_a=>(2/3), :enum_b=>(1/1)}
```

If you keep incrementing `enum_a` by `(1/3)` and `enum_b` by `(1/2)`, the yield ratio of their elements will be 3:2.

Finally, the `rescue` clause handles enums running out of elements. If this happens, that enum is removed from the `counts` hash.

Once the `counts` hash is empty, the loop stops.

Example usage with 3 enums:

```
enum_a = (1..10).each
enum_b = ('a'..'f').each
enum_c = %i[foo bar baz].each

combine_enums_with_ratio(enum_a => 3, enum_b => 2, enum_c => 1).to_a
#=> [1, "a", 2, 3, "b", :foo, 4, "c", 5, 6, "d", :bar, 7, "e", 8, 9, "f", :baz, 10]
#    <--------------------->  <--------------------->  <--------------------->
#             3:2:1                    3:2:1                     3:2:1
```

Comment: Nice! I suppose it should've occurred to me that looping over a set of input enums could end up shorter than all my "a" and "b" code. That's pretty neat!